# libev webserver reading files

Tags: c, file, webserver, reactor, libev

When creating a small webserver with libev in C, what is the best strategy to serve files (open, ready, write to socket) without blocking the reactor?

I have across some recommendations to read a few blocks at a time but I am not sure this would be the right approach.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have across some recommendations to read a few blocks at a time but I am not sure this would be the right approach.

Yep, this is a pretty standard approach.

If you are on Linux you may like to use [`sendfile()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sendfile.2.html). This way you don't have to maintain a buffer into which it reads a file in blocks and then sends it through a socket.